# How to split an RDD into different RDD's based on a value and give every part to a function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD in which every element is a case class, like this:
`case class Element(target: Boolean, data: String)`
Now I need to split the RDD based on what the String data is (it is a discrete variable). 
And then execute a function `def f(elements: RDD[Element]): Double` on every split.

I have tried to make a pairRDD like this: `val test = elementsRDD.map(E => (E.data, E))` so I have (key, value) pairs but I don't know what to do after this (how to split them because groupBy gives back Iteravle(V) and not an RDD of all the values).

I could also filter on each possible value of `data: String` and execute function f on the results. But I don't know all the possible values that ´´´data: String´´´ can take in advance. And it doesn't seem efficient to first go over all the data to check the different possibilities and then also filter over it multiple times.

So is there a way it can be done efficiently?

Comment: I don't really see a different way than first fetching all the distinct `data` values, and then filtering the original RDD to create `N` different RDDs. The problem is that `f` takes an RDD as an argument. Could we have more insight as to what `f` does? For example, if `f(elements) = elements.count()`, the problem is easily solved with a simple aggregation.

Comment: f calculates the entropy, so it counts the amount of elements which have target = true and target = false and the total. Then it returns: -((AmountTrue/total)*log2(AmountTrue/total) + ((AmountFalse/total)*log2(AmountFalse/total)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need to do is count by aggregating by `data`, depending on the 2 values that the boolean can take. The rest is a simple computation that only depends on these 2 values.

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(Element(true,"a"),Element(false,"a"),Element(true,"a"),
    Element(false,"b"),Element(false,"b"),Element(true,"b")))

val log2 = math.log(2)

// calculate an RDD[(String, (Int, Int))], first element of the tuple is the number of "true"s, and the second the number of "false"s
val entropy = rdd.map(e => (e.data, e.target)).aggregateByKey((0, 0))({
  case ((t, f), target) => if (target) (t + 1, f) else (t, f + 1)
}, {
  case ((t1, f1), (t2, f2)) => (t1 + t2, f1 + f2)
}).mapValues {
  case (t, f) =>
    val total = (t + f).toDouble
    val trueRatio = t.toDouble / total
    val falseRatio = f.toDouble / total
    -trueRatio * math.log(trueRatio) / log2 + falseRatio * math.log(falseRatio) / log2
}

// entropy is an RDD[(String, Double)]
entropy foreach println
// (a,-0.1383458330929479)
// (b,0.1383458330929479)
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer using a DataFrame:

```
import spark.implicits._

val rdd = sc.parallelize(
      Seq(Element(true,"a"),Element(false,"a"),Element(true,"a"),
        Element(false,"b"),Element(false,"b"),Element(true,"b")))

val log2 = math.log(2)

var df = rdd.toDF()

val groupedData = df.groupBy($"data")
  .agg(count(when($"target" === true, 1)).alias("true"),count(when($"target" === false, 1)).alias("false"))
  .withColumn("total", $"true" + $"false")
  .withColumn("true ratio", $"true" / $"total")
  .withColumn("false ratio", $"false" / $"total")
  .withColumn("entropy", -$"true ratio" * log($"true ratio") / log2 + $"false ratio" * log($"false ratio") / log2)
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+----+----+-----+-----+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|data|true|false|total|        true ratio|       false ratio|            entropy|
+----+----+-----+-----+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|   b|   1|    2|    3|0.3333333333333333|0.6666666666666666| 0.1383458330929479|
|   a|   2|    1|    3|0.6666666666666666|0.3333333333333333|-0.1383458330929479|
+----+----+-----+-----+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```